# How to overwrite text-align

Tags: html, css, xhtml

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    Big lol
    <div style="margin-left: 50px;">
        Small lol
    </div>
</div>
```

I need to move small lol to the left with margin, but the problem is that on the whole page is setup `text-align: center` and i cant remove it.

Comment: The only way to override an inline style is to use `!important` after the declaration in a CSS file.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<div style="text-align: center;">
Big lol
    <div style="margin-left: 50px; text-align: left;">
    Small lol
    </div>
</div>
```

The property `text-align: left` from the second `div` will overwrite the property `text-align: center` from the first `div`. Usually, when you need to overwrite a property of a parent container just use a value that you need for the same property. Hope it helps.

Comment: Do not abuse of `!important` rule in your own CSS file (if you feel the need for `!important` then you need to review your CSS/HTML code. The `!important` rule is meant "to create a balance of power between author and user style sheets. By default, rules in an author's style sheet override those in a user's style sheet". For more details: [read here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html)

Comment: Feel free to use !important. It has helped me tremendously over the years and has saved my many hours of work. 

There is no reason not to use it if you know what you are doing.

I've used it in the same project for 12 years now and so far have failed to see the negative aspects that everybody has been whining and warning about.

Answer (score 1):

Add `!important`

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px !important; text-align:left !important">
        Small lol
    </div>
```

Demo here http://jsfiddle.net/z8yna/1/

Comment: It only moves to the left with no margin.

Comment: Add !important to margin too. I have added demo in the answer

Comment: You don't need to add `!important` to the margin, unless the margin has been overridden somewhere else as well. But given your current conditions, Sowmya's answer should suffice.

Comment: According with @anothershrubery don't need to add !important to the margin-left.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
<div style="text-align: center">
    Big lol
    <div style="margin-left: 50px; text-align:left !important">
        Small lol
    </div>
</div>
```

With !important you can override the style parent

Comment: maring should be margin :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to set `text-align` on the element: change

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px;">
```

to

```
<div style="margin-left: 50px; text-align: left;">
```

If this does not have the desired effect, then the cause is in some setting that was not disclosed in the question. In that case, the cure depends on the disease, i.e. on that specific setting and how it has been made.